# Set the missing category value in Seaborn's FacetGrid

Tags: python

I have a large data that have group, location and count. A sample of the data is below. I want to make a chart showing the count of each location for each group. There are six unique locations, but some groups don't have all locations. For example, group H has only 5 locations. When doing a Facetgrid chart, I want to set the missing location to be 0 (in this case add a location B in group H and set it to be 0). Is there a way to do this in Seaborne?

```
group location count
H      A        2
H      C        30
H      D        2
H      E        2
H      F        52
O      A        1
O      B        7
O      C        27
O      D        2
O      E        3
O      F        45
```

This is what I tried:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='group', col_wrap = 2)
g.map(plt.bar,'location', 'count')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
uniques_loc = df['location'].unique()
df = df.set_index('location') \
      .groupby('group',group_keys=False)\
      .apply(lambda s: s.reindex(uniques_loc).fillna(pd.NA))\
      .reset_index()


# Optional: to fit desired output
df['group'] = df['group'].fillna(method="ffill")
df['count'] = df['count'].fillna(0)
```

**Explanations:**

1. Find unique location values using [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html): `df['location'].unique()`
2. On the dataframe, set the `location` as index using [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
3. Group on `group` column using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
4. Reindex each group using [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html)
5. Fill missing values using [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)
6. Reset index using [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
7. Optional: To fill `NA` values use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna)

---

**Full code:**

```
uniques_loc = df['location'].unique()
df = df.set_index('location') \
      .groupby('group',group_keys=False)\
      .apply(lambda s: s.reindex(uniques_loc).fillna(pd.NA))\
      .reset_index()

df['group'] = df['group'].fillna(method="ffill")
df['count'] = df['count'].fillna(0)

print(df)
#    location group  count
# 0         A     H    2.0
# 1         C     H   30.0
# 2         D     H    2.0
# 3         E     H    2.0
# 4         F     H   52.0
# 5         B     H    0.0
# 6         A     O    1.0
# 7         C     O   27.0
# 8         D     O    2.0
# 9         E     O    3.0
# 10        F     O   45.0
# 11        B     O    7.0

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='group', col_wrap = 2)
g.map(plt.bar,'location', 'count')
plt.show()
```

*Output*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am hoping to fill in H in group and 0 in count for row 5. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Yes, sure. You can use `fillna`. See the update.